# How to get a single item from a GoInstant collection?

Tags: angularjs, goinstant, goangular

How do you get a single item from a GoInstant GoAngular collection?  I am trying to create a typical show or edit screen for a single task, but I cannot get any of the task's data to appear.

Here is my AngularJS controller:

```
.controller('TaskCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $goKey) {

    $scope.tasks = $goKey('tasks').$sync();

    $scope.tasks.$on('ready', function() {
        $scope.task = $scope.tasks.$key($stateParams.taskId);
        //$scope.task = $scope.tasks.$key('id-146b1c09a84-000-0'); //I tried this too
    });
});
```

And here is the corresponding AngularJS template:

```
<div class="card">
    <ul class="table-view">
        <li class="table-view-cell"><h4>{{ task.name }}</h4></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Nothing is rendered with {{ task.name }} or by referencing any of the task's properties.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might handle these tasks: (a) retrieving a single item from a collection, and (b) responding to a users direction to change application state differently.

Keep in mind, that a [GoAngular model](https://developers.goinstant.com/v1/GoAngular/model/index.html) (returned by `$sync()`) is an object, which in the case of a collection of todos might look something like this:

```
{  
    "id-146ce1c6c9e-000-0": { "description": "Destroy the Death Start" },
    "id-146ce1c6c9e-000-0": { "description": "Defeat the Emperor" }
}
```

It will of course, have a number of methods too, those can be easily stripped using the [`$omit`](https://developers.goinstant.com/v1/GoAngular/model/omit.html) method.

If we wanted to retrieve a single item from a collection that had already been synced, we might do it like this ([plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YDrVAocMdFUfk1njpIMJ?p=info)):

```
$scope.todos.$sync();

$scope.todos.$on('ready', function() {
  var firstKey = (function (obj) {
    for (var firstKey in obj) return firstKey;
  })($scope.todos.$omit());

  $scope.firstTodo = $scope.todos[firstKey].description;
});
```

In this example, we synchronize the collection, and once it's ready retrieve the key for the first item in the collection, and assign a reference to that item to `$scope.firstTodo`.

If we are responding to a users input, we'll need the ID to be passed from the view based on a user's interaction, back to the controller. First we'll update our view:

```
  <li ng-repeat="(id, todo) in todos">
      <a href="#" ng-click="whichTask(id)">{{ todo.description }}</a>
  </li>
```

Now we know which todo the user want's us to modify, we describe that behavior in our controller:

```
$scope.todos.$sync();

$scope.whichTask = function(todoId) {
  console.log('this one:', $scope.todos[todoId]);

  // Remove for fun
  $scope.todos.$key(todoId).$remove();
}
```

Here's a working example: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YDrVAocMdFUfk1njpIMJ?p=info).  Hope this helps :)